# How can I Connect to BigQuery from my SQL VM

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a VM (with SQL image) that is in project A in my GCP organization, and BigQuery in project B. **I cannot connect to BigQuery from my VM.**
I tried peering the two projects, but since they uses default vpc, I get error Overlapping addresses. Everything is in production so I am not sure if i can use shared vpc whitout impact.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What's a SQL image? And BigQuery has public APIs, if you have a public IP on your VM, you should be able to access BigQuery, if not, use CloudNAT

Comment: Also...what is the error? Besides networking it might be IAM